# Unique lists from a list

Tags: python

Given a list I need to return a list of lists of unique items. I'm looking to see if there is a more Pythonic way than what I came up with:

```
def unique_lists(l):
    m = {}
    for x in l:
        m[x] = (m[x] if m.get(x) != None else []) + [x]
    return [x for x in m.values()]    

print(unique_lists([1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,8,9]))
```

Output:

```
[[1], [2, 2], [3], [4], [5, 5, 5], [6], [7], [8, 8], [9]]
```

Comment: Thank you for Counter, groupby and defaultdict solutions! I learned something new today.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> L=[1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,8,9]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> [[k]*v for k,v in Counter(L).items()]
[[1], [2, 2], [3], [4], [5, 5, 5], [6], [7], [8, 8], [9]]
```

Comment: I originally posted a solution that was one line shorter by simply using the list's built in count method, but gnibbler makes the excellent point that list.count() is O(n), making my algorithm O(n^2).  +1

Comment: There's no reason that the creation of the `Counter` can't be folded into the list comprehension here: `[[k]*v for k, v in Counter(L).items()]`.

Comment: My rule of thumb is to automatically elide temporaries that are only written once and read once, unless they represent significant complexity ("flat is better than nested").

Answer (score 2):

Using default dict.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> b = defaultdict(list)
>>> a = [1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,8,9]
>>> for x in a:
...     b[x].append(x)
...
>>> b.values()
[[1], [2, 2], [3], [4], [5, 5, 5], [6], [7], [8, 8], [9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the build in function `set()` useful very often:

```
lst=[1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,8,9]

def all_eq_elms(lst, elm):
    while True:
        try:
            yield lst.pop(lst.index(elm))
        except:
            break

[[e for e in all_eq_elms(lst,elm)] for elm in set(lst)]

Out[43]: [[1], [2, 2], [3], [4], [5, 5, 5], [6], [7], [8, 8], [9]]
```