# Get unique objects from multiple lists and lists of lists. Then create a new list with unique objects from all the lists

Tags: python

**My Data set is mixed having lists and lists of lists. So I need to get unique objects from the lists or lists of lists but couldn't find any success. Input data set is as follows:**

> [[1, 2, 39], [1, 2, 39], [3], [[3], [4, 14, 63, 65], [66, 68, 82, 94]], [[5, 8, 31, 34], [36, 37, 42, 44], [55]], [6, 91], [[7, 35, 60, 71], [73, 83, 95, 98]], [[5, 8, 31, 34], [36, 37, 42, 44], [55]], [9, 72], [[10, 22, 30, 32], [38, 51, 56, 87], [89, 92]], [11], [12], [13, 90], [[4, 14, 63, 65], [66, 68, 82, 94]]]

Output Required:

> [[1, 2, 39], [3], [4, 14, 63, 65], [66, 68, 82, 94], [5, 8, 31, 34], [36, 37, 42, 44], [55], [6, 91], [7, 35, 60, 71], [73, 83, 95, 98], [9, 72], [10, 22, 30, 32], [38, 51, 56, 87], [89, 92], [11], [12], [13, 90], [66, 68, 82, 94]]

```
abc=[]
for x in pool:
    if x not in abc:
        abc.append(x)
```

I am not getting that how can I choose distinct object of the list consisting of lists and lists of lists. Any help will be appreciated.

I have consulted multiple sources but nothing solves my problem. Few of them are as follows:

[Unique lists from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936840/unique-lists-from-a-list)

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-unique-values-list/

[Creating unique list of objects from multiple lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031736/creating-unique-list-of-objects-from-multiple-lists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could flatten the list out with a generator then loop over the generated values and add to the result if it hasn't been seen. Something like:

```
def flatten(l):
    for item in l:
        if isinstance(item[0], list):
            yield from flatten(item)
        else:
            yield item

seen = set()
unique = [] 

for l in flatten(l):
    if tuple(l) in seen:
        continue
    seen.add(tuple(l))
    unique.append(l)

print(unique)
```

**Result**

```
[[1, 2, 39],
 [3],
 [4, 14, 63, 65],
 [66, 68, 82, 94],
 [5, 8, 31, 34],
 [36, 37, 42, 44],
 [55],
 [6, 91],
 [7, 35, 60, 71],
 [73, 83, 95, 98],
 [9, 72],
 [10, 22, 30, 32],
 [38, 51, 56, 87],
 [89, 92],
 [11],
 [12],
 [13, 90]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your list is set to a variable called my_list. You access any object from the first scope of this list with a normal index. 
`my_list = [[1, 2, 39], [1, 2, 39], [3], [[3], [4, 14, 63, 65], [66, 68, 82, 94]], [[5, 8, 31, 34], [36, 37, 42, 44], [55]], [6, 91], [[7, 35, 60, 71], [73, 83, 95, 98]], [[5, 8, 31, 34], [36, 37, 42, 44], [55]], [9, 72], [[10, 22, 30, 32], [38, 51, 56, 87], [89, 92]], [11], [12], [13, 90], [[4, 14, 63, 65], [66, 68, 82, 94]]]                                                                                         print(my_list[2])`

This code above will print the 2nd index of my_list, which happens to be a list containg only the number 3

To access a list inside a list, specify the next index. At `my_list[3]` this object holds 3 lists. `[3], [4,14,63,65], and [66,68,82,94]`

To choose the second list of these 3,
`print(my_list[3][1])` 
first we choose one index `[3]` which holds 3 lists then specify another index on that list `[1]` which will give you `[4,14,63,65]`
To go another index deeper and retrieve an object from the list at `my_list[3][1]`,add another index. 14 is at the [1] index of this list so to access it would be `my_list[3][1][1]`

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate each element in your data set to check if it is type = class "List". If so further element need to be checked. Here is the sample code you may refer

```
result = []
for list_item in list1:
 for element in list_item:
    if not isinstance(element, list) and list_item not in result:
        result.append(list_item)

    elif isinstance(element, list)and element not in result:
        result.append(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

**This Worked for me:**

```
 pool_list = []
    #Remove Nested Pools
    def reemovNestings(l):
        for i in l: 
            #if type(i) == list: 
            if(True==any(isinstance(el, list) for el in i)):
                reemovNestings(i) 
            else: 
            pool_list.append(i)

    reemovNestings(pool)
    print("Nested Pools Removed : \n" ,pool_list , "\n")

    #Remove identical pools
    unique = []
    for i in pool_list:
        if i not in unique:
            unique.append(i)

    print("Final Pool : \n ", unique)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a flat list and you don't need to preserve order

```
def unique(input):
  return list(set(input))
```

If preserving order is important you want an ordered dictionary.

[Does Python have an ordered set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set)